Using RxJs Http Polling in Angular to avoid Http timeout for long-running backend process
I am in a situation where few of my Web Api endpoints take 2-5 minutes to prepare and send response but my DNS (cloud flare) or/and the browser times-out the Http request after 60/100 seconds; to resolve this I am trying to implement the Http Polling via RxJs in Angular (v8); here is my client code:
const sub = interval(50000)
    .pipe(
        switchMap(
            () => this.httpClient.get(this.apiUrl+'/TasksAnalysis',{ params: this.filterArgs})
        ), 
        takeWhile(({ status }) => {
            console.log(status);
            return status.value != 0;
        })
    )
    .subscribe((i) => {
        console.log(i);
        //this.data.data_list = i['Table'];
    });

This is my ASP.NET api endpoint:
[HttpGet, Route("TasksAnalysis")]
public HttpResponseMessage TasksAnalysis(string pars = "", string vals = "")
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = new EntityBase().GetDataSet("web.spTasksAnalysis", pars, vals);
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") };
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        new Helper().LogError(exc);
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new StringContent("{ \"error\": \"" + exc.Message + "\" }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") };
    }
}

On my backend I can watch that after few hits response is ready on time but I am unable to stop requests from the client.
What am I doing wrong?

Your rxjs code looks fine. As long as the condition is met, the subscription should stop. Are you sure the result is what your code expects?

Yes, I believe, but I am also unable to add a breakpoint in takWhile() body.
